# Impact of Server Restart in Application pool

Tags: windows-server-2008, iis-7, application-pools

The question is small. I just want to know, is there any effect of server restart on my IIS application pools?  Will the application pool be recycled on server restart?

Answer (score 0):

If your server reboots, all the contents of memory are gone when it comes back up. So of course, there's an impact on your application pools.

Am I misunderstanding your question?

Comment: Ya you are correct. But i have situation where i am failed to give the reason for the below question. Can you please help in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27937594/system-rename-affects-the-iis-application-running-in-anonymous-authentication